# To show that % % does not exist

Tags: batch-file

This code needs to know that if I type "go west" and the number represented by "p" does not exist it will tell me that it does not exist. Here is the code.

```
:type
set /p menu=type:
if "%menu%" == "go north" goto north
if "%menu%" == "go south" goto south
if "%menu%" == "go east" goto east
if "%menu%" == "go west" goto west

:north
set /a p=%p%+50
goto %p%

:south
set /a p=%p%-50
goto %p%

:east
set /a p=%p%+1
goto %p%

:west
set /a p=%p%-1
goto %p%
```

If the code has the number 300 and by typing "go west" "P" equals 301, It needs to say that that number does not exist. I don't want to have that number being type and under it says it does not exist. Example,

```
:301 
echo does not exist
pause
goto play
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer.

```
set movew=0
set movee=0
set moven=0
set moves=0
This is set up before the ":type".

:north
if %moven% equ 1 goto moven
set /a p=%p%+50
goto %p%

:south
if %moves% equ 1 goto moves
set /a p=%p%-50
goto %p%

:east
if %movee% equ 1 goto movee
set /a p=%p%+1
goto %p%

:west
if %movew% equ 1 goto movew
set /a p=%p%-1
goto %p%
```

This make sure then the player moves in that direction the computer does not add or subtract to %p%.

```
:300
set moven=1
echo
pause
goto play
```

If the player try's to move north it goes to "moven".

```
:moven
echo this does not exist
pause
goto play
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit of a weird code, but I have tested this and it does work. add this to the `goto %p%` and it should work:

```
goto %p% || start fail.bat&exit
```

You will need to make another file called "fail.bat" which will need to contain the following code:

```
echo Does not exist
pause>nul
start (Whatever your file is called).bat
exit
```

Basically, the two lines (||) mean that it will carry out the following action on fail of finding the subroutine. So on fail of finding the variable of p, it will start fail and exit, before being restarted by fail.bat.

Hope this helps!


*Source:*http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html

Comment: Is there any way to do this without making a new file?

Comment: I don't think so because when batch cant find a something it has been asked to goto, it just exits, and when you use ||. the command after it cannot contain goto or call.

Comment: Unless you were to add every single possible number, which would take a while.

Comment: Besides using || there has to be a different way.I just don't want to have two batch files. It works for now.

Comment: Actually, you could use `|| start %~n0&exit` which would restart itself. That may work.

Comment: The "|| start %~n0&exit" because my game is a several numbers. Would there be a way to have it were you use number position. Example :play sets m to equal 0. The numbers set m to equal plus 1. Then have a if number equals 0 goto play. Something like that

Comment: Is there a way to put :%P% under the numbers so that once it goes through the list it will see :%P% and read that as a number.

Comment: maybe at the end of all the numbers have :%p% but im not sure if that would work because it my go straight there every time.